# Is this a bug in the node.js http module?

Tags: http, node.js, tcp

I reported the following issue: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/3269

I am trying to establish if this is actually a bug - or expected behaviour.

Shouldn't the connection be reused since we are only dealing with one host? (and http 1.1)

As a side note... *if* there were multiple hosts, I can see that this could happen. What's the best way to avoid port starvation in the case of multiple hosts?

(I am talking about the protocols here, not specific languages)

Generally speaking, what is normal behaviour for a webrequest in the case of port starvation? to fail? or wait?

Comment: we faced something similar a long time back when we were load testing a component. we changed registry parameters as mentioned here. This may help you if you are facing it on Windows - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560610(v=bts.20).aspx .... Ignore the Biztalk part of it and see the Resolution section

Comment: Thank you. There is also a solution to the problem I was facing in the linked question. I'm not trying to work around the problem here, I'm trying to establish whether this is in fact a bug, or not, and understand the protocols more.